# Error time_zone mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a payment host and I presented the following problem. to define and execute my time zone function now returns a date 7 days in carrier delays , you write to technical support and tell me it's my mistake . but I think it is wrong of them . .[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poA4a.jpg)

Whose mistake is it ? mine or theirs?

Comment: PHP has a timezone [setting](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) and so does mysql. So your question needs to be tweaked

Comment: ok, Thanks , I just interested in mysql

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Did you have a question?  It looks to me like the system clock on the server hosting MySQL is off by seven days.... being that today is March 29th, and `SELECT NOW()` is returning 10pm March 21st. What result do you get when you **`SET time_zone='+00:00'; SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %T');`**  (i.e. set the time_zone to UTC and have the query return a string.)

Comment: I 'm trying to access phpmyadmin and when not loaded , but my question is , the error I have it or them?